# Collecting a collection of list based on similar index

Tags: java, loops, collections, java-8, iteration

I have a collection like : 
`List<List<Object>> firstList`

I want to group together a similar list of pattern : 
`List<List<Object>> secondList` 
but grouped by indexes.

say

```
firstList [1]:
   0 = {Object A}"
   1 = {Object B}"
   2 = {Object C}"

firstList [2]:
   0 = {Object A}"
   1 = {Object B}"
   2 = {Object C}"
```

I want to group this collection as

```
secondList [1]:
   0 = {Object A}"
   1 = {Object A}"

secondList [2]:
   0 = {Object B}"
   1 = {Object B}"

secondList [3]:
   0 = {Object C}"
   1 = {Object C}"
```

What I have tried so far is

```
for (int i = 0; i <firstList.size() ; i++) {
    List<Object> list = firstList.get(i);
    List<Object> rlPr = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int j = 0; j <list.size()-1; j++) {
        rlPr.add(list.get(i));
    }
    secondList.add(rlPr);
}
```

But I am not getting what is expected.
I am using java 8.

**EDIT : ALL THE LIST ARE OF SAME SIZES**

Comment: @michael
Correct. That was a typo. I have corrected the same. Thanks!

Comment: Try with a `Map<Integer, List<Object>>` having indexes as keys and after parsing the source list get the values from the map

Comment: So you don't want to "group by index", but group by item? You seem to be throwing away the original index, and maintaining the same object several times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Map` to group the values by index:

```
Map<Integer, List<Object>> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (List<Object> objects : firstList) {
    for (int i = 0, l = objects.size(); i < l; i++) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(i, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(objects.get(i));
    }
}
```

And then to get the `List` back:

```
List<List<Object>> secondList = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Comment: The most succinct and elegant solution, also the most expressive one. I'd upvote this more than once if possible

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, most elegant solution of all. Thanks @Lino.

Comment: `int i = 0, l = objects.size(); i < l` why not just `int i = 0; i < objects.size()`  ?

Comment: @Michael that's purely opinion based, I prefer invoking a method with a constant outcome only once and save the value in a variable. Also you may never know if the `List.size()` method does any additional computation, which would reduce the performance (probably still dismissible impact though)

Comment: @Lino I don't think so. You've sacrificed readability for no tangible performance benefit at all. If you care about the method call, you should initialize the variable before the loop, give it a meaningful name like `length`, and make it final. Using a loop initializer for any effectively final variables is misuse because when I read it I need to scan the entire loop body just to make sure you haven't changed it.

Comment: @Michael for this example I would say that the impact of writing it in the initializer is managable, as the for loop body is only a single line. I agree with the readability in general though, one does not really gain anything when writing the `l` inside the for-loop (except that it is scoped)

Answer (score 2):

First, get the max length of a sublist. In your case, both are 3. Iterate over all these indices, getting the value from each sublist at this index and collecting those to a new sublist.

```
final int maxLengthOfSublist = list1.stream().mapToInt(List::size).max().orElse(0);
final List<List<Integer>> list2 = IntStream.range(0, maxLengthOfSublist)
    .mapToObj(idx -> list1.stream()
        .filter(sublist -> idx < sublist.size())
        .map(sublist -> sublist.get(idx))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will work even if the sublists are different lengths.

Comment: Generic solution for different sizes of lists

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lists inside the main list are all the same size, you can do something like this...

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    public class OhCrikey {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<List<String>> lists = Arrays.asList(
                    Arrays.asList("1a", "2a", "3a"),
                    Arrays.asList("1b", "2b", "3b"),
                    Arrays.asList("1c", "2c", "3c")
            );

            List<List<String>> result = transform(lists);

            result.forEach(System.out::println);
        }

        private static <T> List<List<T>> transform(List<List<T>> lists) {
            if(lists == null || lists.isEmpty()) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            // Check each sub-list contains the same number of elements
            checkAllSameSize(lists);

            // Initialise the results list
            List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>();

            // Get the size of each sub-list
            int totalLists = lists.get(0).size();

            // Fill up the results list with 'totalLists' empty lists
            for(int k = 0; k < totalLists; k++) {
                result.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }

            // For each input list...
            lists.forEach(list -> {
                // Iterate over it and add the kth element to the kth result list.
                for(int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++) {
                    result.get(k).add(list.get(k));
                }
            });

            return result;
        }

        private static <T> void checkAllSameSize(List<List<T>> lists) {
            int size = lists.get(0).size();

            // Make sure each list has the same size as the first list
            lists.forEach(list -> {
                if(list.size() != size) {
                    throw new AssertionError("All child lists must have same number of elements.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Prints...

```
    [1a, 1b, 1c]
    [2a, 2b, 2c]
    [3a, 3b, 3c]
```

Comment: Works well as expected. But logic used is quite big. Lino's answer seems to be a bit compact comparatively.

Answer (score 0):

A stream way of doing it would be (replaced `Object` with `CustomObject`):

```
List<List<CustomObject>> secondList = new ArrayList<>( // Collection to ArrayList
       firstList.stream() // Stream<List<CustomObject>>
                .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<CustomObject>
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())) // Map<CustomObject, List<CustomObject>>
                .values()); // Collection<List<CustomObject>>
```